# Replace if else with a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, replace

I have:

```
    if (a[i] == 1) {
        howMany[1] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 2) {
        howMany[2] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 3) {
        howMany[3] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 4) {
        howMany[4] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 5) {
        howMany[5] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 6) {
        howMany[6] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 7) {
        howMany[7] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 8) {
        howMany[8] += 1;
    }
    else if (a[i] == 9) {
        howMany[9] += 1;
    }
```

I want to replace it with something like:

```
    if (a[i] == 1 || a[i] == 2 <-- etc) {
        howMany[i] += 1;
    }
```

But that doesn't work. Anybody has a clue?
This is C++, but I've experienced the same issue in Python,
so I don't think it's a language issue but rather just
a general problem.

Comment: Are you sure you want to accomplish this with a for loop rather than the one-line answers provided?

Comment: Actually I decided to use the one liner. Thanks guys! I really wanted to see a for statement out of curiosity. It was a relatively simple problem that I could not wrap my head around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the range of `a` is from one to nine you can simply write

```
howMany[a[i]]++;
```

otherwise you will need one `if` statement

```
if(a[i] >= 1 && a[i] <= 9)
    howMany[a[i]]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
howMany[a[i]] += 1;
```

(or `++` rather than `+= 1`) inside the `if` statement (not a loop, by the way) since `a[i]` is the variable holding 1, 2, etc.

Your new `if` statement could also be simplified to something like:

```
if ((a[i] >= 1) && (a[i] <= 9)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
howMany[a[i]] += 1;
```

since you are always accessing the element of `howMany` based on the value of `a[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at what you are doing

```
if (a[i] == 1) {
    howMany[1] += 1;
}
```

So if `a[i]` is 1 then you want to increment the value of `howMany[1]`.  Since `a[i] == 1` and index of `howMany == 1` then all you need is `howMany[a[i]] += 1;`